# Encapsulate ViewHolder Functionality for reuse

Tags: android, android-fragments, encapsulation, android-viewholder

I have an application with a news feed.  I am using a recycler view to populate my news feed.  I have 10 variations of viewholders for the recycler view depending on what type of content received from the server. 
That all works fine.

My problem is when the user clicks on the item in the recycler view the user is brought to a new fragment, with the content and all the comments below.

My issue is this is a new fragment, so I'm outside of the recycler view.  In this case I have to inflate the layout of the item clicked on in the recyclerview and that's fine.  However, it should have all the functionality the item in the feed as, so for example, play media (video, audio), navigate to new fragments.

My question, is it possible to someway encapsulate the functionality of the viewholder in the recyclerview?  Otherwise the same functionality will be repeated.

Any help is appreciated.[image]

I've attached a drawing to help illustrate.

Comment: I think this should solve your problem: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: Are you having problem showing `Fragment Replies` ?

Comment: @ChintanSoni  no, there's no problem displaying replies.  I require the functionality from the viewholder outside the viewholder in a new fragment

Comment: @ChintanSoni that's what I ahve implemented already with my multiple view holders, however, it's the functionality within the viewholder I need to reuse.

Comment: Have you managed to succeed?

Answer (score -1):

```
class VideoViewHolder(
private binding: VideoItemBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

companion object {
    fun create(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        viewGroup: ViewGroup
    ): VideoViewHolder {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<VideoItemBinding>(
            inflater, R.layout.item_video, viewGroup, false
        )
        return VideoViewHolder(binding)
    }
}


fun bind(video: Video){
    // bind view to video model
    // set click listeners
    // fire network request on click events and on response check if the viewholder is binded to same model else its has been reused.

}
}
```

From Video Adapter

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            return VideoViewHolder.create(inflater, parent)
    
    }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    
            when (holder) {
                is VideoViewHolder -> {
                    holder.bind(item as Video, doubtsRepo)
                }
            }
    }
```

To reuse in activity/fragment/ container layout without adapter manually create viewholder and call its bind function

```
val vh = VideoViewHolder.create(inflater, parent) 
// get view from vh.binding.root and manually add it to view container and then bind the model to the view to reuse view holder functionality without any changes.
vh.bind(video)
```

Comment: Don't put fragments inside viewholders

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what issues do you see ?

Comment: Unless you use inflated fragments with `<fragment` in the XML, you can't really be certain what the result of that would be.